# How to convert Image url to Byte Array in java?

Tags: java

i'm trying to make a webscraper with aws image recogntion api. So I have to convert the image to a byte array in order for the api to work. However, I'm getting some error saying `The method openStream() is undefined for the type String`. If i use a local image file, then it works perfectly fine.     Can someone please help me ?
Thanks

```
public class HelloAppEngine extends HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */
         // where jsoup images are stored 

    static ArrayList<String> testImages = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public static void getimages() {
        
        String photo =  testImages.get(0);
        
    

    ByteBuffer imageBytes = null;
    try (InputStream inputStream = photo.openStream())) {
        imageBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
    }
    
    catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.defaultClient();

    DetectLabelsRequest request = new DetectLabelsRequest()
            .withImage(new Image()
                    .withBytes(imageBytes))
            .withMaxLabels(10)
            .withMinConfidence(77F);

    try {

        DetectLabelsResult result = rekognitionClient.detectLabels(request);
        List <Label> labels = result.getLabels();

        System.out.println("Detected labels for " + photo);
        for (Label label: labels) {
           System.out.println(label.getName() + ": " + label.getConfidence().toString());
        }

    } catch (AmazonRekognitionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `photo` variable is of type `String`, and class `String` doesn't have an `openStream()` method. May be you want to call `openStream()` of class `URL`. That would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the URL class to do a openStream. I expect photo to be the location of the image.

```
new URL(photo).openStream()
```